# How to mock a method that is defined in multiple classes with same name

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, xunit, nunit-3.0

I have a factory method

```
public abstract class PFact 
{
   public abstract ResponseMessage P(Model request);
}
```

and I have different classes which overrides this method.

```
public class one : PFact 
{
    public override ResponseMessage P(Model request)
    {
        return response
    }
}

public class Two : PFact 
{
    public override ResponseMessage P(Model request)
    {
        return response
    }
}
```

and in another class I am calling these methods using

```
 var result = _F["One"].P(model);
 var result2 = _F["Two"].P(model);
```

I was trying to mock result and result 2 but a could not able to complete it.
I am trying like

```
var mock = new Mock<PFact>()
mock.Setup(x => x.P(model)).Returns(response);
```

This is not mocking those classes one and two.

How can I explicitly mention both classes to mock separately for writing test case.
I need to mock result and result2. please suggest me!

Comment: what is `mock`? In order to mock something, you need either an abstract or a virtual member. You cannot mock non-overridable member. However it's not really clear to me why you even want to mock anything at all. Maybe it gets clearer if you showed what you want to test here.

Comment: How do you indicate the member isn't mocked? Did you debug the issue step by step to see what the parameters are in your test and what `theFact.P(myModel)` returns? Also is `myModel` what you expect it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Moq library (which I assume you are using) can only provide mock implementations of virtual methods on concrete classes.

If you change your abstract method in `PFact` to be virtual:

`public virtual ResponseMessage P(Model request) {}`

Then you can create a mock for each class and provide different implementations.